# How to change LightDM's background without using sudo and without specifying an image on /home?

Tags: permissions, lightdm, wallpaper

I have a script that I use to change my wallpaper. I'd like it to change the background presented by LightDM when I turn the computer on too, however:

1) Using an image on /home means that LightDM won't be able to read it unless I'm logged in.
2) Using `sudo` to copy the file to `/usr/share/backgrounds` everytime I want to change my wallpaper is impractical.

Is there a way to avoid using sudo, and another place to store the wallpaper? Making `/usr/share/backgrounds` a public folder with `chmod` is an option?

Comment: Edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf` file.

Comment: Not using lightdm-gtk though. I'm using Lightdm Slick (`lightdm-slick-greeter`). And how come editing the configuration file will help, if the issue is about folder access?